# Xamarin.forms content page layout

Tags: xaml, layout, xamarin.forms

I have content page in my xaml file. I have a Stacklayout with orientation vertical in it. I want to put a dialog in middle of content page above this stacklayout. Please suggest some way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to provide dialogs that feel native to the platform your on is through using the [UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) plugin.

If you want to create something of your own you would probably have to come up with something like this:

```
<Grid>
  <StackLayout>
    ...
  </StackLayout>
  <Grid IsVisible="{Binding ShowMessage}">
     <Label Text="Message" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The nested Grid will act as an overlay of sorts spanning your entire page.

Comment: @Priyankasinghal please accept it as an answer if it helped you